# How to wait until all js scripts have been loaded in IONIC(AngularJS)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm working with IONIC/AngularJS and I have a lot of JS Scripts.

I have seen that sometimes when the app is loading, some of the script is not loaded yet, so failed to login in the app (I have a login screen at first).

This is all my scripts:

```
<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src=" lib/Pouchdb/pouchdb-4.0.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ng-cordova.js"></script>
    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/a0-angular-storage/dist/angular-storage.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/ion-affix/ion-affix.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular-qr/angular-qrcode.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular-qr/qrcodejavascript.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-jwt.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/date.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-locale_es-es.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular-elastic/elastic.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular-filter/dist/angular-filter.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/underscore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/qrcode_V2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/factoryutils.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Toast.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.urlshortener.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

    <script src="lib/ionic-material/ionic.material.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ngprogress.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/MenuCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/HomeTabCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/LoginCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/TabEventosCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/DatabaseCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/HandleTokenValidity.js"></script>
```

My error is the next:

> ```
> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPreferredLanguage' of undefined
>   at Object.getPreferredLanguage (file:///android_asset/www/js/ng-cordova.js:2826:32)
>   at file:///android_asset/www/js/LoginCtrl.js:76:39
>   at processQueue (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:23394:28)
>   at file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:23410:27
>   at Scope.$eval (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:24673:28)
>   at Scope.$digest (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:24484:31)
>   at Scope.$apply (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:24778:24)
>   at done (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:19191:47)
>   at completeRequest (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:19363:7)
>   at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:19304:9)", 
>     source: file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js (21157)
> ```

The problem starts when trying to access to `$cordovaGlobalization` scope but I think that the library associated is not loaded at that time.

**My question is if there is any way to make the application to wait until all the JS scripts have been loaded?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your are looking for `ionic.Platform.ready()`

```
ionic.Platform.ready(function(){
  // will execute when device is ready, or immediately if the device is already ready.
});
```

[Link to documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/utility/ionic.Platform/)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I will be testing it. I don't know if with it the problem will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the following code in your app.js file,

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform){
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // The $ionicPlatform.ready event is called when Cordova's deviceready event fires
  });
});
```

It will executes, when your all the js files are get Loaded...